# DJUS sector data

Tags: r, quantmod

How can I get data on Dow Jones Industry sectors? I have no trouble getting individual stock symbols. However, market sector data such as DJUSTC ( ie $DJUSTC or ^DJUSTC) don't seam to work in Yahoo or Google.

Answer (score 1):

[This Yahoo! Help article](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_FIN&locale=en_US&id=SLN2332&impressions=false) says

> ... Yahoo! is no longer licensed to provide data downloads for the Dow Jones Index.
>
> At this time, Dow Jones Industrial Average [^DJI] data can only be viewed on the screen. It can no longer be downloaded.

I believe that extends to other Dow Jones indexes beyond the Industrial Average because there is no link to download the csv at http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EDJUSTC+Historical+Prices

Presumably Google has a similar agreement with Dow Jones.